# How to approximate a number to a n number of decimal places?

Tags: math, maxima

I have started using `maxima` just a few weeks ago (actually I have just used it a few times) with the `wxMaxima` interface for OS X.

I have tried to find a solution for this around the web, but maybe because I am blind or maybe because I do not have much experience in searching in the official documentation of maxima, I have not find a concrete solution yet.

How do I approximate a number to a `n` number of decimal places? For example, if I use `float(22/7)`, it gives me this huge number `3.142857142857143`, but I just want for example to approximate it to the 3rd decimal place `3.143`.

Answer (score 9):

`fpprec` controls the actual number of significant digits in a Maxima bigfloat. That applies only to bigfloats and not to ordinary (fixed precision, IEEE 754) floats.

See also `fpprintprec` which controls how many digits are printed, which applies to bigfloats and to ordinary floats alike. So another solution for you is:

```
(%i1) fpprintprec : 4 $
(%i2) float (22/7);
(%o2)                                3.143
```

Comment: Well, it does not only controls how many digits are printed, but you can also approximate a variable. `fpprintprec : 4, x:float(%pi);`. `x` will then contain `3.145`. Am I right?

Comment: @Rinzler No, `fpprintprec` doesn't have any effect on the value of a variable (neither float nor bigfloat). When you assign `float(%pi)` to `x`, it is the same value no matter what `fpprintprec` is. Try changing `fpprintprec` and output `x` again. You will see different numbers of digits.

Comment: Is there a way to change the variable? I would need for example to compare some results (which I need to approximate to 3 decimal digits) of a function to the approximate value of the number of euler `2.718`, instead of comparing to the number given my maxima...

Comment: @Rinzler I'm not sure I understand what you want. It sounds like using `fpprec` and `bfloat` is what you want, since you want results that have varying precision, and ordinary floats have fixed precision. But maybe you can say more about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to define

```
decimal_places(ex,n):=parse_string(printf(false,sconcat("~,",n,"f"),ex));
```

E.g.

```
decimal_places(22/7,4);
```

But, beware of numerical rounding (internal) caused by representing decimal numbers as binary floats.

E.g.

```
printf(false,"~,1f",1.45);
```

returns 1.4

```
printf(false,"~,3f",0.0145);
```

returns 0.015.

This is *not* bankers' rounding either (which "round" does by the way...
Compare `round(1.5);` with `round(2.5);`).

Comment: This turned out to be trickier than I thought at first glance ... anyway a definition of the decimal places function which doesn't involve string operations is this: `dp(e, n) := block([m], m: ceiling (log(float(e))/log(10.0)), float(e)*10^(n - m), round(%%), %%*10.0^(m - n))`. E.g. `dp(%e, 3)` => 2.72, `dp(1000*%e, 3)` => 2720.0, `dp(%e/1000, 3)` => 0.00272.

Comment: A couple of comments about `decimal_places` as shown above. (1) One can indicate a variable precision in the output of printf by using `v` in the `~f` formatter, e.g. `printf(true, "~,vf~%", 4, 1.234567)` outputs 1.2346. (2) The rounding performed for `~f` format isn't well-defined for inputs ending in `5`. Maxima `printf` punts to Common Lisp FORMAT, and the CL spec says that the rounding for inputs ending in `5` can be rounded up or rounded down -- it is left to the Lisp implementation. This is, I believe, an unfortunate deficiency in the spec.

Answer (score 3):

```
rnddp(x,dp):=float((round(x*10^dp)/10^dp));

rndcdp(z,dp):=rnddp(realpart(z),dp)+%i*rnddp(imagpart(z),dp);
```

`rnddp` will round its first argument to the number of decimal places provided in the second argument.

`rndcdp` does the same for complex numbers.

The result(s) are the approximated values, not just displayed values.

Comment: `rnddp(0.5,0)` gives `0.0`, it should give `1.0`

Answer (score 2):

I have not found a way to approximate a number using [`float`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_5.html#Item_003a-float), but I found a way of approximating using [`bfloat`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_5.html#Item_003a-bfloat).

From the [official documentation](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_5.html#Item_003a-bfloat):

> bfloat (expr)
>
> Converts all numbers and functions of numbers in `expr` to bigfloat
>   numbers. The number of significant digits in the resulting *bigfloats*
>   is specified by the global variable `fpprec`.

Thus, I can achieve more or less what I wanted by using something like this:

```
bfloat(%e), fpprec:4;
```

And the output is:

```
2.718b0
```

If someone knows how to do it using the `float` function, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

x:3.14159;

x:x*10000;

x:floor(x+0.5);

x:x/10000;

float(x);

"3.1416"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).